# Read header of CSV separately

Tags: php, csv

I am reading a large CSV file through `fgetcsv()`. I want to read the header of the file and the data separately. Below is my code. Any help?

```
$msg_row = 1;
while (($result = fgetcsv($msg_file,1000, ",")) !== false)
{   
    $msg_data[] = $result;
    $msg_row++;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So call it once first?

```
$msg_row = 1;
$header = fgetcsv($msg_file, 1000, ",");
while (($result = fgetcsv($msg_file, 1000, ",")) !== false)
{   
    $msg_data[] = $result;
    $msg_row++;
}
```

Comment: That was quick and easy. Thanks @minitech